# Stabilizers: If $X$ is a $G$-set and $x, y \in X$ such that $y=hx$ for some $h\in G$, show that $G_x$ and $G_y$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, group-isomorphism

If $X$ is a $G$-set and $x, y \in X$ such that $y=hx$ for some $h\in G$, we need to show that $G_x$ and $G_y$ are isomorphic (where $G_x$ represents the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$).

I was able to prove that $G_y = hG_x h^{-1}$. Can I use this to prove the isomorphism between $G_x$ and $G_y$  or it proves the bijection?

Comment: The map $\phi: G_x \to G_y$ sending $g \in G_x$ to $hgh^{-1}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Every pair of conjugate subgroups of a group are isomorphic (but not conversely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, yes.

Conjunction by $h$ is an isomorphism from $G_x$ to $G_y$. Its inverse is conjugation by $h^{-1}$.

Showing that it is a homomorphism is routine. Indeed, for $s,t\in G_x$, we have

$$\begin{align}
h(st)h^{-1}&=hseth^{-1}\\
&=hs(h^{-1}h)th^{-1}\\
&=(hsh^{-1})(hth^{-1}).
\end{align}$$

---

Recall that $$hG_xh^{-1}=\{ hah^{-1}\in G\mid a\in G_x\}.$$